# How come INT_MAX and INT_MIN resolve in C++ without <climits>

Tags: c++

How come the following code works even though I am not including `<climits>` library?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int min = INT_MIN;
  int max = INT_MAX;
  cout << min << endl;
  cout << max << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
git:(master): g++ main.cpp                                                                    
git:(master): ./a.out                                                                         
-2147483648
2147483647
```

```
g++ -v                                                                          [INS] 5:21AM
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Have you looked inside the `<iostream>` header? Maybe that incudes others?

Comment: which compiler ? With what flags? Does not compile here: https://godbolt.org/z/E3qTsb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementations of standard library headers may, in turn, include *other* standard library headers as needed to perform their goals.

However, this is an internal detail that can (and will!) differ between toolchains, and should not be relied upon.